# Filtering data with radio button (animated map)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, button, gis

I have animated slider map that takes lat/long data and displays it based on when a type of building has been erected. Currently, I am only able to display data for skyscrapers, however I would like each of the buttons to filter data for "residential" and "hospitals" as well.

d.skyscrp is what is pulling the date data from data5001.txt, and then moment() is parsing the data as information to be read by the browser. I need to access d.residential and d.hospitals as well. So far I am able to load the data, but do not know how to make the buttons filter out what i need.

I have a [full working example](http://bl.ocks.org/dyavromEPA/5e4f3b99c2162466a7c66767937419de) here on bl.ocks with all the code available.

[Plunker of code located here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oavLy0IhBcuU9SDspY4r?p=preview)

[image]

Index.html below as well for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Map</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="d3.slider.css"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="d3.slider.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
        <div id="update">
            <div id="agegrp" class="buttons">
                            <div class="button current" data-val="1" onclick = "updateData()" id = "option" name="updateButton"
                               type="button" value = "Update">Button1</div>
                            <div class="button" data-val="2">Button2</div>
                            <div class="button" data-val="3">Button3</div>
                            <div class="button" data-val="4" style="margin-right:0">Button4</div>
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- @end #update -->

    <div id="title">
        </div>

    <div id="subtitle">
        </div>

        <div id="axis1985">
            <h8></h8>
            </div>

        <div id="axis1990">
            <h8>1990</h8>
            </div>

            <div id="axis1995">
                <h8>1995</h8>
                </div>

                <div id="axis2000">
                    <h8>2000</h8>
                    </div>

                    <div id="axis2005">
                        <h8>2005</h8>
                        </div>

                        <div id="axis2010">
                            <h8>2010</h8>
                            </div>

                            <div id="axis2015">
                                <h8>2015</h8>
                                </div>

    <div id="slider3">
        </div>

        <div id="slidertextplaceholder"></div>
        <div id="slidertext"></div>


        <div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton"
           type="button"
           value="Update"
           onclick="updateData()" />
</div>

<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 850;

var mapPath = "usa.json";

// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1080)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json(mapPath, function(error, us) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "land-boundary");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a !== b && (a.id / 1000 | 0) === (b.id / 1000 | 0); }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "county-boundary");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "state-boundary");


  d3.tsv("data5001.txt")
    .row(function(d) {
      return {
        permalink: d.permalink,
        lat: parseFloat(d.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(d.lon),
        state: d.state,
        fullAddress: d.fullAddress,
        buildingName: d.buildingName,
        skyscrp: moment(d.skyscrp,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
        residential: moment(d.residential,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
        hospital: moment(d.hospital,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
            };
    })
    .get(function(err, rows) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
      window.site_data = rows;
    });
});



//display the sites using "permalink"
var displaySites = function(data) {
  var sites = svg.selectAll(".site")
      .data(data, function(d) {
        return d.permalink;
      });

  sites.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "site")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return projection([d.lng, d.lat])[0];
                        })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return projection([d.lng, d.lat])[1];
            })
                 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                 div.transition()
                         .duration(200)
                         .style("opacity", .9);
                 div.html("building Name:" + "<br>" + d.buildingName + "<br>" +  "<br>" + "Address:" + "<br>" + d.fullAddress + "<br>")
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                 })
             .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                 div.transition()
                        .duration(200)
                      .style("opacity", 0);
            })
  .attr("r", 1)
  .transition().duration(800)
    .attr("r", 7);

  sites.exit()
    .transition().duration(200)
      .attr("r",0)
      .remove();
};

var minDateYear = moment('1985-12-19', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
var maxDateYear = moment('2017-09-29', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
var secondsInDay = 60 * 60 * 24;

d3.select('#slider3').call(d3.slider()
  //.axis(true).min("1986").max("2017")
    .axis(false).min(minDateYear).max(maxDateYear)
  .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
    var newData = _(site_data).filter( function(site) {
      return site.skyscrp < value;
    })
    //console.log("New set size ", newData.length);
     //console.log("svg value ", newData);
     document.getElementById("slidertext").innerHTML = "Achieved Goals:  " + newData.length;
    displaySites(newData);
  })
);

document.getElementById("slidertextplaceholder").innerHTML = "Achieved Goals:  " + " ____ " + "buildings";
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You already filter the `site_data` according to the date. Can't you just filter it by building type in the same way?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Now, I'm just not sure how to link the button to the data so that when i click it, the new data appears. for what it is worth, i had used code found here on bl.ocks and reconfigured it for my dataset...http://bl.ocks.org/cmdoptesc/fc0e318ce7992bed7ca8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pull your filter out into shared code.

Here is how I would go about it:

```
// First, a variable to keep the year we're filtering on.
var yearMin = 0;
// Another one to keep track of the building type we're filtering on.
var buildingType = 'skyscrp';

// Shared function
function filterData() {
  var newData = _(site_data).filter(function(site) {
    return site[buildingType] < minYear;
  });
  displaySites(newData);
  document.getElementById("slidertext").innerHTML =
      "Achieved Goals:  " + newData.length;
}
```

I've made a few assumptions, but the basic idea is I filter on year and also on building type in the same statement.

So each of the buttons will set `buildingType` to an appropriate value. After setting the value of `buildingType`, they call `filterData();`.

```
function buttonClick(filterField) {
  if (filterField !== undefined) {
    console.info('Changing building filter to', filterField);
    buildingType = filterField;
  }
  console.info('Applying filter');
  filterData();
}
```

Then, for the slider, you modify the code like this:

```
d3.select('#slider3').call(d3.slider()
  .axis(false).min(minDateYear).max(maxDateYear)
  .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
    console.info('Changing year filter to', value);
    minYear = value;
    filterData();
  })
);
```

**Edit**

Looking at the data, it seemed to me more likely that you want to filter on a different field, depending on the selected button. For example, right now you're filtering on `skyscrp`, but there are also `hospital` and `residential` fields.

So, using the same strategy as before, I just altered the `filterData` function, yielding a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oY9QOFeoEAAeDJde?preview).

These are the changes I made, reflected in the code above:

1. Added an `onclick` handler to your first three buttons. Each button sends through one of the three field names 'skyscrp', 'hospital' or 'residential'. I also changed their titles to match the filters they apply, but you'll want to do something extra to update the styling on the screen to show which filter is active - I don't think that falls in the scope of your question.
2. Added the `buttonClick` function which, as explained before, simply sets the filter and calls `filterData()`. But instead of a number representing the building type, I now use the actual field name in your data.
3. Updated `filterData` to now use that field for the comparison.

**Edit 2**

Updating the label now happens within `filterData`, which gives a more consistent experience.

Comment: Hi Corbus,
Thanks! Spent a few hours trying to get this to work, and learning a lot here! Couple q's...

1. Where in the code does the button onclick filter out the data? I do not see any connection with the buttons
2. It seems that buildingType would require a new data column where each building type is assigned a value of 0-3. Is this correct?

I tried to replicate your code in a new plunkr, (cleaning up some minor issues as well).  Whats wrong is that all dates show up at once, and the buttons still dont filter. Here is my plunkr...
http://plnkr.co/edit/6Ddffz1UJYIdcq18fyU6?p=preview

Comment: @DeebaYavrom I don't know the full data structure you're working with, so when you spoke about filtering on building type, I just did a very naive implementation of that. The basic strategy will work however you want to modify the filter though:
1. Create a function that does the filtering, based on fields accessible to all your code.
2. For each filter (year slider, filter button, or whatever), you set the appropriate field and call the filter function.
You could easily scale this to many more than two filters.

Comment: @DeebaYavrom To more explicitly answer your questions: 1. Your `onClick` will set the global field and call `filterData()`. It's trivial enough that I didn't think I had to show it. 2. As I said before, that was a naive implementation to explain my point. You can do any kind of check you want.

Comment: @DeebaYavrom Actually, I think I get what you're trying to do. I'll do a quick update. I'll still use the same strategy, just a slightly different filter.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Corbus, the data structure is in the plunkr if needed. No rush on my end, and ill work on your suggestions a bit until you update. Best.

Comment: @DeebaYavrom I've made the update a few hours ago already. It does what I think you want.

Comment: Wow Corbus, thank you so much. this looks amazing. Also big thanks for the explanation, i totally understand your reasoning!  One more question, "return newData.length" does not update onclick. Is there anyway to show this so that when you click on a new filter, the line that says "Archived Goals" gets updated with the new length of the data column? I will also need to create a background color change onclick for the buttons, but ill figure that out myself, you have been more than helpful. And if there is anything I can do to show my gratitude, please let me know!

Comment: @DeebaYavrom If you need to always update the label when changing the filter, just move it into the `filterData` function, as with the latest update. And I'm happy to help - if you found this useful, you can just accept the answer and we'll be all square ;)